# How to add nofollow noopener in rel of Wordpress comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, nofollow

By default, I am getting WordPress comment's external URL as `rel="nofollow"`. But, I want to make it `rel="nofollow noopener"` in my theme without plugins. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I used below code in function.php

```
function replace_add_blank_noopener($comments_text){
    return str_replace('rel="nofollow"', 'rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"', $comments_text);
}
add_filter('comment_text', 'replace_add_blank_noopener');
```

And called it in comments.php to print.

```
replace_add_blank_noopener(comment_text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function add_noopener($content) {
$content = preg_replace_callback('/]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i', function($m) {
    if (strpos($m[1], "YOUR_DOMAIN_ADDRESS") === false)
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="noopener" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    else
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    }, $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_noopener');
```